# Symfony2.7 PhpUnit: simple functional test doesn't work when just assertEquals($statusCode, $var)

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I've dicided to code now (from 2016 !) with dynamic test for all my project by using Symfony2 and it default Test framework PhpUnit and I wrote my very simple functional test to check wether the status code of one of my page (home page) is right but it faild "Faild asserting that 302 matches expected 200" although manually, Symfony show in the toolbard that it success (200).

```
public function testDashboard()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context. How does your controller look like? Will it really always return the same response?

Answer (score 2):

302 status code is redirection. Maybe that route / is behind a firewall and you are redirected to login page in your test, while you testing it in a browser are already logged in. Maybe that / route is doing some redirection and in the toolbar you see 200 for the route you have been redirected to. Just dump `$client->getResponse()` and see all fileds, like content and headers. If's it's 302 redirect you need "Location" header to see where you are redirected to. Maybe that will give you clue what's happening.

Comment: it's true because of the firewalls but how can I desable the firewalls in the test environment ?

Comment: @Saint-CyrMAPOUKA You could have a security configuration file that is imported only in `test` environment and overwrites the default security configuration (this is done in subclasses of `Kernel`, usually `AppKernel`). Take a look at how `symfony/symfony-standard` is doing it in its environments.